# Should we move to GIT completely from GIT-SVN

Tags: git, git-svn

We use git-svn since the very beginning of our development. Is it a better idea to move to pure git?

We use to commit and checkout our code on a lot of different environments and machines. Currently we use svn to checkin/checkout code on remote machines and git-svn on development machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git can completely replace your git-svn infrastructure if you want.

Simply consider changing the central SVN repository by a "central" git repository.

If you don't depend specifically on SVN (like client software for your "remote" machines, user credentials to access code base, ...), it is a good idea to use one tool to do the job.

Git is usable on popular platform like Windows, MAC-OS and of course Linux.

On the practical side, simply clone the git-svn repo, using the `--bare` option, like that:

```
git clone --bare /path/to/mygit-svn-repo/
```

and export it to a "central" location. Then add this remote repository to your .git/config and keep on coding!